# Android: How to stop all active Media Players?

Tags: java, android, media-player

I have a app with some buttons.
On a Tab on one of these buttons a sound will be played.

Example code:

```
public void button1(View a) {
    MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(Home.this, R.raw.button1);
    mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
    mp1.start();
}

public void button2(View b) {
    MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(Home.this, R.raw.button2);
    mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
    mp2.start();
}
```

...

Is there a way to stop all MediaPlayers for example on a "Stop all Sounds"-Button?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ArrayList where you put all your mediaplayers in and stop them while looping.